# Quartz job exists even after deleting it?

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, jobs

I was testing a helloworld quartz job. I copied an existing job and pasted it in grails-app/jobs folder. I named it TestJob.groovy. I simply made it to fire every minute with a println message. I had made a mistake in the cron expression. I deleted this job and restarted the app and i get the following error message. The strange thing is looks like the file still exists since the error mentions the error was in the file TestJob.groovy but i had already removed this file. I tried cleaning the project and rebuilding it and i still get the error. I appreciate any help in resolving this error and restarting back the app normally. Thanks!

```
  | Loading Grails 2.2.0
    | Configuring classpath.
    | Environment set to development.....
    | Packaging Grails application.....
    | Compiling 1 source files.....
    | Running Grails application
    ERROR context.ContextLoader: Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class grails.plugins.quartz.DefaultGrailsJobClass
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class grails.plugins.quartz.DefaultGrailsJobClass
        ... 4 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        ... 4 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cron expression '0 * * * * *' in the job class com.runnercard.RemoveUserCodeJob is not a valid cron expression
        at grails.plugins.quartz.config.TriggersConfigBuilder$_prepareCronTriggerAttributes_closure5.doCall(TriggersConfigBuilder.groovy:204)
        at grails.plugins.quartz.config.TriggersConfigBuilder$_closure1.doCall(TriggersConfigBuilder.groovy:216)
        at grails.plugins.quartz.config.TriggersConfigBuilder.prepareCronTriggerAttributes(TriggersConfigBuilder.groovy:198)
        at grails.plugins.quartz.config.TriggersConfigBuilder.createTrigger(TriggersConfigBuilder.groovy:78)
        at grails.plugins.quartz.config.TriggersConfigBuilder.createNode(TriggersConfigBuilder.groovy:251)
        at grails.plugins.quartz.config.TriggersConfigBuilder.createNode(TriggersConfigBuilder.groovy:244)
        at com.runnercard.RemoveUserCodeJob$__clinit__closure1.doCall(TestJob.groovy:14)
        at grails.plugins.quartz.config.TriggersConfigBuilder.build(TriggersConfigBuilder.groovy:51)
        at grails.plugins.quartz.DefaultGrailsJobClass.evaluateTriggers(DefaultGrailsJobClass.java:57)
        at grails.plugins.quartz.DefaultGrailsJobClass.<init>(DefaultGrailsJobClass.java:47)
        ... 4 more
    ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader: Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class grails.plugins.quartz.DefaultGrailsJobClass
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class grails.plugins.quartz.DefaultGrailsJobClass
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class grails.plugins.quartz.DefaultGrailsJobClass
        ... 4 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        ... 4 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cron expression '0 * * * * *' in the job class com.runnercard.RemoveUserCodeJob is not a valid cron expression
        at grails.plugins.quartz.config.TriggersConfigBuilder$_prepareCronTriggerAttributes_closure5.doCall(TriggersConfigBuilder.groovy:204)
        at grails.plugins.quartz.config.TriggersConfigBuilder$_closure1.doCall(TriggersConfigBuilder.groovy:216)
        at grails.plugins.quartz.config.TriggersConfigBuilder.prepareCronTriggerAttributes(TriggersConfigBuilder.groovy:198)
        at grails.plugins.quartz.config.TriggersConfigBuilder.createTrigger(TriggersConfigBuilder.groovy:78)
        at grails.plugins.quartz.config.TriggersConfigBuilder.createNode(TriggersConfigBuilder.groovy:251)
        at grails.plugins.quartz.config.TriggersConfigBuilder.createNode(TriggersConfigBuilder.groovy:244)
        at com.runnercard.RemoveUserCodeJob$__clinit__closure1.doCall(TestJob.groovy:14)
        at grails.plugins.quartz.config.TriggersConfigBuilder.build(TriggersConfigBuilder.groovy:51)
        at grails.plugins.quartz.DefaultGrailsJobClass.evaluateTriggers(DefaultGrailsJobClass.java:57)
        at grails.plugins.quartz.DefaultGrailsJobClass.<init>(DefaultGrailsJobClass.java:47)
        ... 4 more
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cron expression '0 * * * * *' in the job class com.runnercard.RemoveUserCodeJob is not a valid cron expression

Comment: show the code. obviously, the problem is in it.

Answer (score 0):

doing a grails clean and clearing .slcache did it. Maybe the cache is the culprit.